# Get the next sequence in an arithmetic or geometric progression

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to make an application that takes a sequence of 3 numbers per line to produce and stops when it reaches a sequence of zeros and then prints if it's an arithmetic progression or geometric progression and the next number in the series.

Example input:

```
4 7 10    
2 6 18    
0 0 0
```

should output

```
AP 13    
GP 54
```

here is my code I wanna know what's wrong with it and what are the possibilities that won't work with my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Main
{
    static String s="";
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    String c;

        String a[];
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        do {
            c= br.readLine();
            a = c.split(" ");
            if(c.charAt(0)!='0'){
            calc(a[1], a[2]);
            }
        }while((c.charAt(0))!='0');
        printer(s);
    }
    public static void calc(String a, String b){
            int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
            if(y%x==0){
                s += "GP" +" " + (y*(y/x)) + "z";
                return;

            }else{
                s += "AP" + " " + (y + (y-x)) + "z";
                return;
            }
}
    public static void printer(String s){
        String p= "";
        for(int i =0;i<=s.length()-1;i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)!='z'){
                p+= s.charAt(i);
            }else{
                System.out.println(p);
                p= "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this part `if(y % x == 0)` is buggy. For example, `0 4 8` is obviously arithmetic progression, but your algorithm will say it is geometric. It is absolutely clear that all 3 numbers should be involved. Another example, `8 4 2` is GP, but `2%4` will return false saying it is AP.

Comment: Thanks I changed it to an if statement of (z-y = y-x) to be an AP and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem it that you discover progression type incorrectly. For example, `0 4 8` is obviously AP, but your algorithm will say it is GP. Another example: `8 4 2` is GP, but `2%4` will return `false`, saying it is AP. Also, you don't proceed cases when offered sequence is not progression at all.

It is absolutely clear that all 3 numbers should be involved. Suppose that integer numbers `a, b, c` form AP or GP, and you need to discover which progression it is. Simple math can be used:

1. If they form AP, then `a + c = b + b`. Next element is `c + c - b`
2. If they form GP, then `a * c = b * b`. Next element is `c * c / b`

*(Please notice how `+` is changed to `*`, and `-` to `/`, when you switch from AP to GP).*

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on the assumption that if two consecutive numbers of a 3 number series is divisible, the series is a GP and that if it's not, it has to be an AP. This assumption is wrong. There are many cases in which it will not be true, such as a series 0,3,6. It is an AP, not a GP. So instead of sending 2 parameters to the function `calc()`, you should send all three numbers as parameters, and check as follows:

```
    if((a+c)==(2*b))
    {//AP
    }
    else if((a*c)==(b*b))
    {//GP
    }
```

These above are the proper check for Arithmetic and Geometric progressions. Also while checking if the inputs are all 0, you are only checking for the first element. Instead you have to see if all three of the elements are 0. Your code might not work in the case of 0,3,6 or 0,2,4 or 0,1,2. So instead you have to check like this:

```
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        if(Integer.parseInt(a[i]))
             flag=1;
    if(flag==1)
    {//continue prog
    }
    else
    {//Terminate prog as input is 0,0,0
    }
```

Comment: `(a+b)==(2*c)` is not correct. Check against `2, 4, 6` for example.